# Need help setting up a class with an attr_accessor

Tags: ruby

I want to achieve what the specs says

```
 describe "Car" do
  describe "initialize" do
    it "should take make, model and year" do
      new_car = Car.new("Acura", "Integra", 1998)
      expect( new_car.make ).to eq("Acura")
      expect( new_car.model ).to eq("Integra")
      expect( new_car.year ).to eq(1998)
    end
  end
```

And this is what I came up with so far and I don't know what to do next.

```
   class Car
  attr_accessor :make, :model, :year
end
```

I need help setting up the rest and an explanation how it works.Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean? `def initialize(make,model,year);@make,@model,@year = make,model,year;end` This is fairly basic have you tried google or any tutorials like tryruby or rubymonk?

Answer (score 0):

below accessors:

```
def initialize(make, model, year)
  @make = make
  @model = model
  @year = year
end
```

Initialize method is called always when you use ::new.

It takes arguments you wrote in ::new and names them properly (in this example make = "Acura" etc.)

```
attr_accessor :make
```

takes @make from initialize and creates another methods for you:
One to read a variable:

```
def make
  @make
end
```

And one to write to variable:

```
def make(str)
  @make = str
end
```

In this particular example

```
attr_reader
```

is enough, there is no need for

```
attr_accessor
```